# Finding a specific edge in an undirected graph between two vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to write an abstract algorithm using graph theory.

Given an undirected and unweighted graph G=(V,E), two vertices: m,n∈V and a specific edge e∈E. I want to check if edge e is a part of all the shortest paths between m and n.

**My algorithm:**

1. do BFS scan from m until reach to n.   \\  O(V+E)
2. int temp <-- d[n]                      \\  O(1)
3. boolean ret                            \\  O(1)
4. take out edge e from G.                \\  O(1)
5. do BFS scan from m until reach to n    \\  O(V+E)

   - if d[n] = ∞, ret <-- true
   - if d[n] == temp, ret <-- false
   - if d[n] > temp, ret <-- true
6. return edge e into G.                  \\  O(1)
7. return ret

**Time Complexity analysis:** O(V+E)

**Memory analysis:** extra O(2) for temp and ret.

What do you say? Is it correct, or you have a better idea with less time complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm seems correct, and will indeed find if `e` is participating in all unweighted-shortest paths.

**Proof:**

- If `e` is in all shortest paths -> removing `e` will negate all this
  paths -> the new shortest path will be longer than the old one -> the algorithm yields the correct answer.
- If `e` is not participating in some shortest path (let it be `p`) -> by removing `e`, the path `p` remains, and thus the shortest distance from `m` to `n` remains the same -> The algorithm yields the correct answer.

**However**, your memory analysis is wrong.

BFS requires `O(V)` extra space, for a visited set - so the extra space is `O(V)`

Answer (score 1):

It would not be O(V+E). The worst case in a breadth first search is that every edge has been searched, at which point if the node has not been found then the search fails. This gives this section a complexity of O(|E|), since this is the dominant calculation, all others O(1), the  complexity is O(|E|).